# Twilio is unable to play .mp3 file

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

So I have a TwiML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Response>
    <Play>https://api.twilio.com/cowbell.mp3</Play>
</Response>
```

As you can see, I want Twilio to play the mp3 file. But whenever I try to get Twilio to play the audio file, I hear the URL being recited instead. Why is Twilio not playing the .mp3 file?

Comment: That is weird! Might be something for [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) to take a look at as your TwiML looks correct.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, did you find any solution? I'm having the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just copied and pasted your [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) to a new [TwiML Bin in the console](https://www.twilio.com/console/dev-tools/twiml-bins) and heard the cowbell as expected.

In the past we have seen a change in the response Content-Type header from `"text/plain"` to `"text/html"` do the trick. But that does not seem to be at play here.

It could also be affected by preceding TwiML instructions if there are any or [return mime type](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/accepted-mime-types#accepted) if you are not actually using the cowbell mp3.

But as Phil suggested, the support crew will have the best insight into what's happening if you send them [Call Sids of calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#instance-properties) displaying this behavior.